# JS hoisting functions. ( Why does this code snippet work? )

Tags: javascript

The following code snippet shows a basic object that contains a variable `str`, a member variable `hello`, and a member function `test`. I thought I knew JS pretty well and expected this code to fail because the `test` function would be hoisted to the top and would be unable to access the `str` or `vm` variable. I was then surprised to see that this actually works. Why does this code function? Does hoisting still occur?

```
function SomeObject( ) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.hello = "hello";
  vm.test = test;
  var str = "testig!";

  function test() { 
    console.log( vm.hello );
    console.log( str );
  } 
}


var s = new SomeObject();

s.test();
```

Output:

```
hello
testig!
```

Comment: Hoisting doesn't affect scope...

Comment: Hoisting always occurs

Comment: Why would it be unable to access the variables? It's still in the same scope.

Comment: How do you believe does the "hoisted code" look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to hoisting, you essentially end up with this:

```
function SomeObject() {
  var vm;
  var str;
  var test;
  test = function test() {
    console.log(vm.hello);
    console.log(str); // Works because we haven't run the function yet
  }

  vm = this;
  vm.hello = 'hello';
  vm.test = test;
  str = 'testig'; // str now has a value, function hasn't been called yet
}

var s = new SomeObject();
s.test(); // Function is called after str has been given a value
```

Comment: Only variable declarations are hoisted. The assignment `vm = this` is not moved to the top. (OK, fixed by Bergi's edit)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the quick fix. That is technically accurate but I can see how the function coming *before* the hoisted variables could still be confusing. Technically, they exist at the same time due to the second pass but that's kind of hard to show while still being technically accurate.

Comment: I just checked the spec, it's more like `var fm, str, test; test = function(){…}`. Feel free to move it below the `var` declarations, as you say it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

All declarations are hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope container.

A function declaration, such as:

```
 function foo(){ }
```

Will be hoisted to the top of its enclosing scope, so it may be called by code that is written BEFORE the function is.

Variable declarations are hoisted as well. So, code such as:

```
 var x = 10;
```

Will experience hoisting as well.  BUT, only declarations are hoisted, so in the previous example, only

```
 var x
```

is hoisted. The `x = 10` assignment won't happen until the actual code location is reached.

Similarly, function expressions work the same way. With this code:

```
 var f = function() {};
```

Only the `var f` is hoisted, not the assignment. If you were to try to call f before the actual code location were reached, you would receive an error indicating that f is not a function.

Your code works simply because when you call:

```
 var s = new SomeObject();
```

The function test is not executed, but all the variable assignments are. So, when the time comes for this:

```
 s.test();
```

All the variables and the function are ready to go.